# Fullscreen within SDL

Tags: haskell, sdl, fullscreen

I’m writting a program in Haskell with SDL. When I do that:

```
screen <- trySetVideoMode width height depth [HWSurface,OpenGL]
```

the program behaves correctly. Now, if I do that :

```
screen <- trySetVideoMode width height depth [HWSurface,OpenGL,Fullscreen]
```

the program starts with a black fullscreen mode, then comes back windowed and goes on that way. I add that the resolution used in the application is 1920x1080 – which is also my screen resolution.

Does anyone know why? How can I make it fullscreen?

Comment: Have you checked if `screen` is `Nothing`? This indicates that SDL failed to set the video mode. You should then be able to get an error message from SDL through [`getError`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/SDL/0.6.4/doc/html/Graphics-UI-SDL-General.html#v:getError).

Comment: yup, I always check it, and it’s not `Nothing` since my app goes on a black screen then windowed (with blits operations on it etc.)

Comment: I’ll try using `getError`, thanks

Comment: or just use directly setVideoMode instead of trySetVideoMode - it'll stop with an exception and message describing an issue